# Properties of numbers...?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

> One has five.
>
> Two has two.
>
> Three and four only have one.

**What does eight have?**

> *hints? who needs hints? :)*

**Updated hints from comments:**

> @ibrahim_mahrir - A hint? I'd suggest to contemplate What, when, where but not why? But that's as likely to be taken the wrong way as the right one....... :) Anyway, it's yours and mine, and a bit superficial too.
> @Adam - the decrease isn't an essential feature [in the sense that, one having more doesn't of itself mean the next ones must have less]. I think that's a safe enough comment :)

**Comments on the puzzle and its hints + answer (ignore this bit!)**

> I found myself looking at an ordinary analog clock on the wall, and thinking about how one never really saw the "1" in "10".  You only tend to see ten as a unit, not it terms of its digits "one" and "zero". A bit like how the eye skips over the the typos in some sentences. The puzzle came full fledged from that. I wasn't sure anyone would get it, I wanted to find out if someone could, on such abstract wording.
> I suspect my comment on the 7-seg guess was too cluey, but it really *was* inspired for closeness. Its hard to hint without narrowing it down. The hints above, well....
> *what/where/when* - *what* are they and *where/when* are they [found], would be more productive than looking for a formula. Asking *why* are they, wouldn't help though. *Mine+yours* = ours ("hours"), and anything *superficial* is talking about things on the face of something (a clock face).

Comment: another related tag maybe ..

Comment: I want this to be fibbonaccian, but it doesn't fit (at all, not even convolutedly)!

Comment: @Adam - it's not :) so you're all safe there

Comment: Either of **mathematics** or **riddle** tags are applicable for this?

Comment: I hope the answer is not too broad.

Comment: I don't think it will prove to be

Comment: A hint please!!

Comment: @ibrahim_mahrir - A hint? I'd suggest to contemplate What, when, where but not why? But that's as likely to be taken the wrong way as the right one....... :) Anyway, it's yours and mine, and a bit superficial too.

Comment: One ___ has five ___, Two ___ has two ___. As they have fewer and fewer, it is because they 'share' in some way. One person has five fingers etc. Is that sort of thinking completely wrong?

Comment: @Adam - indeed completely... well, yep. It is :) That's how it is;  but the decrease isn't an essential feature. I think that's a safe enough comment :)

Comment: Can only numbers have this attribute? (For example, might egg or cow or walk or Simba have three or four or seven or zero?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that Eight has

> 1

because, each number has

> the specified number of instances left of the colon on a standard 12 hour clock in one day

That is:

> One has five (01:XX, 10:XX, 11:XX, 12:XX) Note: there are two in 11
>  Two has two (02:XX, 12:XX)
>  Three and Four only have 1 (03:XX, 04:XX)

Therefore Eight has:

> 1 (08:XX)

---

EDIT / ADDITION:
While describing my solution in comments, I came to the obvious realization that the answer might be more succinctly written as:

> The count of each number's digits in the months of the year.

Comment: Bloody hell. Someone got it. Now that is impressive. For some bonus <something's>, I'd love to hear how you got there.

Comment: My first one - woot!  My not-so-exciting strategy was just to think about it on and off for a long time..   Binary / ASCII / letter / math approaches didn't seem to work out, and it seemed like single-digit and teen numbers had to be involved to get 1 to have more than 2, 3, or 4, and eventually it clicked.  Out of curiosity, was my answer you intended solution - because I realize it might have been more succinctly answered using the edit at the bottom...

Comment: Oh, and the hints were not helpful, unfortunately for me..  I tried to use the "superficial" one for a while, but gave it up after getting nowhere with it..

Comment: Your answer was indeed the intended one, see my update to the OP. I hadn't thought of that alternative which also uses the same values. But not many common things do, so it wouldn't have been too broad if you'd gone with that instead.  Very impressed, and thank you also.

Answer (score 2):

> **0**
> The puzzle essentially describes the function $f(x)=\lfloor \frac5x\rfloor$, or `x => 5 // x` in pseudo-code. The function is integer division with dividend 5. Thus:$$f(1)=5\\f(2)=2\\f(3)=1\\f(4)=1\\f(8)=0$$

Comment: Clever, but I'm not sure that this really matches the non-arbitrary question wording :) ... that said, I'm curious what solutions will be found :)

Comment: @Stilez Remember that if it has many possible solutions, it's very likely too broad.

Comment: I'm kind of hoping it doesn't. After all there are an infinity of formulae for a mathematical riddle, if a formulaic answer is looked for.... but rarely are there many answers having that click of certainty and elegance :) If it turns out I'm wrong, and there are multiple _elegant_ answers, I'll have to add few more hints to narrow it down. But that makes it less elegant, so if possible I'll leave as-is.

Comment: I don't think the verb **have** applies to this example. We don't say _one has five_ if `5 // one == five`.

Answer (score 1):

> If we view the numbers as displays on something like a digital clock, with 7 segments, the answers refer to the number of unlit segments.
> The number 1 uses 2/7 segments, leaving 5. 2 uses 5 segments.
> I'm not sure about 3 and 4 though, if the two displays were overlapping it would leave one unlit. 8 would have 0 in this pattern, as it uses every segment.

Comment: This is clever. Yes, it is a lateral thinking puzzle, I was wondering when lateral thinkers would click the answer button. No, it's not this, but right now you're closer than anyone else to the right kind of mindset / _angle_. In at least two ways! For one thing, it would indeed be a _property of a number_ (on at least most standard 7 seg displays). For another, it's, well.. lateral :)  Howeverrrrr..... that still leaves you quite the wide range of thinking to find it in! :) And it pains me to say, but 7 seg's won't help much more ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> $-9$
>
>  Polynomial fit: $y = - \frac{1}{6}x^3 + 2x^2 - \frac{47}{6} x + 11$

Comment: Some imagination puh-lease :) its a riddle not homework,....... :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, these are corresponding possible

> anagrams of given words

and thereby

> Eight has only one.

As,

> ONE has - EON, ENO, NEO, ONE, (and one more, I could not get it right now)
>  TWO has - TWO, OWT
>  THREE and FOUR - THREE and FOUR

Comment: THREE - ETHER / THERE

Comment: Clever again. I like lateral!  (i.e., No. ;-) )

Comment: And TWO has  TOW

Answer (score 0):

Eight has

> $0$

Because what a number has is the

> Number of its non-zero multiples you can show with the fingers of one hand
>  
>  1 has five multiples: 1,2,3,4 and 5
>  
>  2 has two: 2 and 4
>  
>  3 has only one: 3
>  
>  4 has only one: 4
>  
>  8 doesn't have any

Comment: This is essentially the same answer that was already given.

Comment: @Jason V where is the earlier given answer?

Comment: The first answer (by the Greek name I can't type on a phone) the floor function of 5/x. This is the same answer presented a slightly different way

Answer (score -1):

What about -

> Multiples under 6

Answer would be

Eight has

> Zero