# Properties of numbers, redux...?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

> One has five.
>
> Two and three have two.
>
> Six only has one.

**What does eight have?**

**______**
<sup>An homage to [Properties of numbers...?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/56853/properties-of-numbers) — but a new puzzle</sup>

Comment: Lol, it does seem extremely similar, I really want the answers to be completely different

Comment: The answer to mine completely does not work for the original puzzle, so pretty sure they're going to be very different :)

Comment: Haha, really nice one :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Zero.

It is referring to

> the number of missing segments of the number as displayed on a calculator.