# What do numbers have?

Tags: number-property

Numbers 0 through 9 each have a number of **something**.

0 has 6.
1 has 2.
2 has 5.
3 has 5.
4 has 4.

How many do 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

5 has:

> 5

6 has:

> 6

7 has:

> 3

8 has:

> 7

and 9 has:

> 6

The explanation is:

> These are the number of segments lit up on a 7-segment LED/LCD display for the corresponding numbers. 
>  
>  
>  [image]
>  
>  
>  *Image courtesy Wikipedia's page on [7-segment displays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display)*

Comment: Well, that was super quick!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir we have had a couple of these puzzles posted before.

Comment: Essentially [Properties of numbers, redux...?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/56905/30633) in reverse.